# How to enable jersey trace logging in glassfish

Tags: java, logging, jersey, glassfish

I've been writing RESTful Web service. The technologies that I use: Glassfish 4, JDK 8 & Jersey (part of glassfish).

To troubleshoot an issue, I want to enable trace logging done by jersey classes. For e.g. below is the logging code in the _getMessageBodyWriter() method of MessageBodyFactory

```
 final TracingLogger tracingLogger = TracingLogger.getInstance(propertiesDelegate);
    MessageBodyWriter<T> selected = null;
    final Iterator<MbwModel> iterator = writers.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        final MbwModel model = iterator.next();
        if (model.isWriteable(c, t, as, mediaType)) {
            selected = (MessageBodyWriter<T>) model.provider;
            tracingLogger.log(MsgTraceEvent.MBW_SELECTED, selected);
            break;
        }
        tracingLogger.log(MsgTraceEvent.MBW_NOT_WRITEABLE, model.provider);
    }

    if (tracingLogger.isLogEnabled(MsgTraceEvent.MBW_SKIPPED)) {
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final MbwModel model = iterator.next();
            tracingLogger.log(MsgTraceEvent.MBW_SKIPPED, model.provider);
        }
    }
```

How do I enable this logging through logging.properties file?

Comment: Look in the admin console, there is a section for administering and configuring logging services for all GlassFish's components. Also have a look at the documentation: [About Logging](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/abluk.html#scrolltoc)

Comment: I assume you are referring the Logger Settings link on the instance configuration. Isn't this about jersey logging though?

There are options of adding loggers on the "Log Levels" tab. What loggers should I add to get the above log messages seen in the server.log?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
@ApplicationPath("rest")
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public ApplicationConfig() {
        super();
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        // register your rest classes here
        property("jersey.config.server.tracing.type", "ALL");
        property("jersey.config.server.tracing.threshold", "VERBOSE");
    }
}
```

Set the following in your `logging.properties`:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.level=ALL
```

This will activate jersey trace logging via HTTP headers and `server.log`, you can use something like Firebug or the Chrome developer console to see the headers.

By setting `jersey.config.server.tracing.type` to `ALL` you enable trace logging for every request. You can also set it to `ON_DEMAND`, then you have to add a header named `X-Jersey-Tracing-Accept` (value doesn't matter) to your request for logging.

There is a limit for headers per request in Glassfish, if you reach this limit with the logging you can do this via `asadmin`:

```
set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-1.http.max-response-headers=1000
```

**See also**:

- [How to get jersey logs at server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332515/how-to-get-jersey-logs-at-server)
- [Enabling Jersey trace logging causes MaxHeaderCountExceededException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410503/enabling-jersey-trace-logging-causes-maxheadercountexceededexception)
- [Enabling Jersey trace request logging in Payara](http://onword.co/10803/)
- [How to get JAXRS 2 (Jersey) verbose Trace to work with ResourceConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178500/how-to-get-jaxrs-2-jersey-verbose-trace-to-work-with-resourceconfig)

Comment: I did follow the steps and tried to enable logging in a embedded glassfish app (for debugging purposes) but I don't see the trace logs. Please have a look at the logging.properties file - https://pastebin.com/2ECzuUxJ. I tried to put a debug point in the ApplicationConfig but it seems the constructor is not called. What could be wrong?

Comment: Your logging.properties file looks ok. Can you see the tracing logs in the HTTP headers? Did you use the ApplicationConfig before or did you only added it based on my answer?

Comment: I didn't add the HTTP header since I set ALL for "jersey.config.server.tracing.type". About ApplicationConfig, yes I only added it for enabling logging based on your answer. There isn't any other functional need of it.

Comment: No I mean can you see the HTTP headers in the response? I guess the ApplicationConfig may not get loaded because you have configured your application in a different way. How are you registering your REST classes?

Comment: I see the standard headers. Nothing specific. Please find them here - https://pastebin.com/p8jvxEFA. Here's how I register the REST classes - https://pastebin.com/9fun0wxY and here's the code for starting the embedded jetty server - https://pastebin.com/enuwbq80. Thanks for the discussion so far. Please share your valuable inputs.

Comment: Hmm...I don't really understand why you are using Jetty in your test environment when all the text in the question is about Glassfish? That are 2 completly different things. In your case I guess it could help to add the `LoggingFilter` to `jersey.config.server.provider.classnames` and set `org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.level=ALL` in your jetty-logging.properties.